# Is it possible to display the Notes from a diary event in Google Calendar?

Tags: google-calendar

I'm trying to set up a calendar for my sports club and then embed the calendar in Google Sites.  I'm going to default it to the Agenda view, but when the user opens it up, I'd like them to see the When, Where and Notes, so I can include who is leading the event, or more information (a link to an external website etc).

If this isn't possible, am I able to get a mouse over hover tip to display with the Notes?

Comment: This question has been bumped by Community User 15 times. I’m voting to close this question because  it mentions that the Calendar will be embed in a Google Sites but the edition available at that time was retired and the app that replaces it is not compatible.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you can use **Google Tasks** to show additional information about an event on Google Calendar [like this](https://zapier.com/apps/google-tasks/tutorials/google-tasks-guide). It's like Post-It Notes on your calendar. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that you can not do that exactly with Google Calendar. But as our friend said you can do with 2nd party applications such as Zoho, automate.io, IFTTT..